# Visual Basic Macros email addresses

Tags: vb.net

I have zero knowledge about VB scripting. Basically I want to download an attachment from emails and then save it to a location folder with date stamp, name of the sender and Email of the sender as the file name.
I have found a script which I played around with. Now, apart from the email address, I was able to extract and save the file.
I really want the email address.
Following is the script.

```
Public Sub saveAttachtoDisk(itm As Outlook.MailItem)
Dim objAtt As Outlook.Attachment
Dim saveFolder As String
Dim Space
Space = " "
Dim SenderName
SenderName = Format(itm.SenderName)
Dim dateFormat
dateFormat = Format(itm.ReceivedTime, "mm-dd H-mm-ss")
saveFolder = "C:\temp"
For Each objAtt In itm.Attachments
If InStr(objAtt.DisplayName, ".pdf") Then
objAtt.SaveAsFile saveFolder & "\" & dateFormat & Space & SenderName & Space &     objAtt.DisplayName
End If
objAtt.Delete
Set objAtt = Nothing
Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Just like the attachments, the email address is a property of the `Outlook.MailItem` being passed into the subroutine. You can see the properties available on the MailItem interface [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.mailitem_members.aspx). You'd add something like this to your existing code:

```
objAtt.SaveAsFile saveFolder & "\" & dateFormat & Space & SenderName & Space & itm.SenderEmailAddress & Space & objAtt.DisplayName
```

This gives you access to the MailItem's SenderEmailAddress field the same way you're accessing its SenderName.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your prompt reply. I need the senders email address. I want to save the attachment with the email address for the sender as file name.

Comment: That's just another property of the MailItem interface, listed in the document linked to in my answer. I've edited the answer to demonstrate.

Comment: Hello,no unfortunately it doesn't work. DO i need to tweek the script?